# Link two objects in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got 2 data sets

posts

```
[
 {
  "postId": 1,
  "postContent": "Lorem Ipsum",
  "user": 1
 },
 {
  "postId": 2,
  "postContent": "Lorem Ipsum",
  "user": 2
 },
]
```

and users

```
[
 {
  "user": 1,
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe"
 },
 {
  "user": 2,
  "firstName": "Johny",
  "lastName": "Doey"
 }
]
```

I am repeating all the posts and i would like to access a user data throught the `$scope.post.user.firstName` etc.

how should i aproach it?

Comment: What have you tryed thus far?

Comment: What is your desire output?

Comment: There is a little typo in the users data set btw

Comment: @MathieudeLorimier i am using $resource directive and i've tried to do something like $scope.post.user = user.get({id: $post.user}) also i have found out about .merge() and .extend() functions via google search, but i've decided to ask before implementig one of them

Comment: @MasoodRehman to access user data in a way that is like accessing nested json

Comment: @Aks i've edited, but its not actual data

Comment: @EDGECRUSHER: does your user are sorted by ID ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a method like `getUserById()` with the use of [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to use it when iterating over your posts.

Code in AngularJS:

```js
angular
  .module('App', [])
  .controller('AppController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.posts = [{"postId": 1,"postContent": "Lorem Ipsum","user": 1},{"postId": 2,"postContent": "Lorem Ipsum","user": 2}];
    $scope.users = [{"user": 1,  "firstName": "John",  "lastName": "Doe"},{  "user": 2,  "firstName": "Johny",  "lastName": "Doey"}];

    $scope.getUserById = function (id) {
      return $scope.users.find(function (user) {
        return id === user.user;
      });
    };
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="AppController" class="row">
  <div ng-repeat="p in posts">
    <p>{{p.postContent}} <i>by {{getUserById(p.user).firstName}}</i></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`find()` the matching user for each post.

Note that if you are not using ES6 features, you will need a [polyfill for `Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill) and should use regular `function() {}`s instead array functions.

```js
var posts = [{"postId":1,"postContent":"LoremIpsum","user":1},{"postId":2,"postContent":"LoremIpsum","user":2}];
var users = [{"user":1,"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"},{"user":2,"firstName":"Johny","lastName":"Doey"}];

var out = posts.map(post => Object.assign({}, post, {
  user: users.find(user => user.user === post.user)
}));
                
console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that maps each user object to your post object. Then you can access user details as $scope.post.user.first_name; Here is simple code that will make you an new object with users.

```
var new_object = [];
function mapUsersToPosts(users, posts){
   angular.forEach(posts, function(post){
      angular.forEach(users, function(user){
         if(post.user_id == user.user_id){
            new_object.push({
                'post' : post,
                'user' : user
            });
         }
      });
   });
}
```

Now you can loop new_object and use user data and post data in same object.